# Python split list of items according to a weighting

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, split, weighted

Suppose I have a list of items, let's say integers, that I would like to split in to near equal sized sub lists. That's fairly easy to do with numpy...

```
MyList = range(30)
numpy.array_split(MyList, 3)
```

....or with custom code....

```
nSubLists = 3
subList =[]
i = 0
for item in MyList:
  for i in range(nSubList):
    subList[i].append(item)
  if i > nSubLists:
    i = 0
  else:
    i = i + 1
```

But now suppose that I don't want the  items distributed equally between the subsists. Suppose, I want them distributed according to some weighting

e.g.

```
wgtList1 = 20%
wgtList2 = 30%
wgtList3 = 50%
```

Where the % show the fraction of the items in the original list I want in each sub list. Obviously if the list doesn't split evenly according to the percentages or fractions then it can be the closest integer split.

What's the best way to apply such weightings to the list split in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic solution I can think of would be something like this:

```
def split(original_list, weight_list):
    sublists = []
    prev_index = 0
    for weight in weight_list:
        next_index = prev_index + math.ceil( (len(my_list) * weight) )

        sublists.append( my_list[prev_index : next_index] )
        prev_index = next_index

    return sublists

## function call ##
my_list = [...] # whatever your list contains
weight_list = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] # This equals to your 20%, 30% and 50%

sublists = split(my_list, weight_list)
```